# Reg ex for getting HSH NORDBANK

Tags: regex

Reg ex for getting HSH NORDBANK  from 23-MAR-15 11220647 HSH NORDBANK AG - SINGAPORE 25-MAR-15 27-APR-15 33 6.2089 100,000,000.00 CNH/USD 144.95 *

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: No attempts as of now ...new to regex ...required help urgently

Comment: REG EXP for not selecting an expression

Comment: No it is not working :(

Comment: You might like to explain in what way it is not working.  The answer I posted DOES work for the data you provided.

Comment: Without any other constraints, the simplest regex which will match the substring "HSH NORDBANK" is the substring itself. If you have additional constraints, please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
^(?:\S+\s){2}([^-]*).*$
```

will give you "HSH NORDBANK AG".

In short it skips the first two fields (things separated by whitespace) and then captures everything up to the hyphen.

Alternatively this, for example

```
^(?:\S+\s){2}(\S+\s+\S+)
```

will give you just "HSH NORDBANK", by discarding the first two fields and capturing the next two.

I fear it may not work in the general case, but you've only given one example to go on...